# Split csv file using lambda expression

Tags: java, java-8, refactoring, java-stream

I'm trying to refactor this method to use a lambda expression:

```
 public List<String> getHttpsLinksFromCsvList() {
        List<String> data = getDataFromCsv();
        List<String> httpLinks = new ArrayList<>();

        data.forEach(System.out::println);
        for (String value : data) {
            String[] arrayString = value.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);

            for (String item : arrayString) {
                if (item.endsWith(".git")) {
                    httpLinks.add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        //httpLinks.forEach(System.out::println);

        return httpLinks;
    }
```

Ideally I want to get remove the two nested for loops and optimise it a bit. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<String> httpLinks = getDataFromCsv().stream()
        .map(value -> value.split(COMMA_DELIMITER))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .filter(item -> item.endsWith(".git"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```